# Generate deterministic ID for each instance of a repeated component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

I have an Angular 5 component that can be repeated any number of times within its parent. I need a deterministic and unique ID for each instance of that component, which may be based on the component's `@ContentChild` if necessary.

I've tried working through the available properties on the component's ViewContainerRef and on its contained `@ContentChild` in the hope of deriving an ID from the generated DOM elements but it's not getting me anywhere and feels a bit too hacky.

I struggle with the Angular documentation for `ViewContainerRef`, `ContentChild`, `ViewChild` etc. so it's entirely possible I've missed something obvious in the API.

[Here is a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CXhGceJWAaYJgjGeqAFy) demonstrating my configuration. The component requiring a unique ID is `ContainerComponent`.

**ContainerComponent**

```
import {Component, ContentChild, TemplateRef, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="content">
    <h5>Container ID: {{id}}</h5>
    <div style="margin-left: 10px">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class ContainerComponent {

  @ContentChild("content")
  public content: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;

  public get id(): string {
    return "container_?";
  }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div id="parent">
      <app-container>
        <ng-template #content>
          <app-child1></app-child1>
        </ng-template>
      </app-container>
      <app-container>
        <ng-template #content>
          <app-child2></app-child2>
        </ng-template>
      </app-container>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```